# Assembly NASM. While using the FPU and trying to print the result, I get an segmentation fault after executing all the code

Tags: assembly, nasm

Assembly program to compute: 7x^3/(2x^2+1.6) using floating point registers.
Why do I get a segmentation fault error in the following program?

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

The error is after the entire program has been executed. The output is not working for some reason, but there is no problem at the stage of passing, I don`t understand, please help

Sorry for my English :)

```
%include "io.inc" ; файл опису регістрів

section .data
    x: dd 1
    sum1: dd 1.6
    format_float: db "Result = %0.4f", 10, 0
ret
    
section .bss
    res resb 4
        
section .text                ; секція оформлення програми
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov EBP, ESP             ; для правильного налагодження
    xor EAX, EAX             ; обнулення регістрів
    xor EBX, EBX
    xor ECX, ECX
    xor EDX, EDX
 
FOR:   
    finit  
    mov dword [esp], 7  
    fild dword[esp]      ; sp0 = 7
    fimul dword [x]      ; sp0 = 7*x
    fimul dword [x]      ; sp0 = 7*x*x    
    fimul dword [x]      ; sp0 = 7*x*x*x
    
    mov dword [esp], 2
    fild dword[esp]      ; sp0 = 2, sp1 = sp0 = 7*x*x*x
    fimul dword [x]      ; sp0 = 2*x
    fimul dword [x]      ; sp0 = 2*x*x
    mov dword [esp], __float32__(1.6)
    fadd dword [esp]     ; sp0 = 2*x*x + 1.6
    fdiv                 ; sp0 = sp1/sp0
    fstp dword[res]      ; res = sp0

    
printRes:    
    finit
    sub esp, 8               ; резервація стеку для подвійного стеку
    mov ebx, res             ; переміщення результату в регістр ebx
    fld dword [ebx]          ; завантаження в стек числа
    fstp qword [esp]         ; вивантаження і зберігання його в esp в вигляді qword
    push format_float        ; завантаження в стек форматного рядка
    call printf              ; виклик С функції для друку
    add esp, 12 
    
increment:    
    add byte [x], 4
    cmp byte [x], 18
    JNG FOR
   
ret
```

Comment: You forgot to make space on the stack for the various constants you move to `[esp]`, so you kill your return address.

Comment: @fuz I don't understand a bit how the calculation of the right amount that needs to be released in esp is done. Could you explain this point in more detail or at least in what direction to look for the necessary information?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help :)

To solve the problem, I wrote `sub esp, 4` after the stack was initialized, and finally changed `add esp, 12` to `add esp, 16` to free up memory.